# I would like to store the ID in a variable present in a specific line

Tags: scripting, rhel

I have this line in my file.

### Capacity - Base ID:205

I want to retrieve 205 and store it in a variable.
Any suggestions.?

Comment: Google or use man about grep and how to store grep output to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Here's a few of them:

```
string='Capacity - Base ID:205'

variable="$(echo "$string" | awk -F: '{print $2}')"
variable="$(echo "$string" | cut -d: -f2)"
variable="$(echo "$string" | grep -o '[^:]*$')"
```

They all store `205` into `$variable`.  And they all work by extracting the portion of the string after the `:` character.  The first two (`awk` and `cut`) assume there will be only 1 `:` character, the last one (`grep`) just captures everything after the last `:` in the file, no matter how many there are.

Answer (score -1):

```
STRINGT=$(grep -m1 "BASE ID" ${file}); ID=${STRINGT:-3:3}
```

This worked